# How to have animated number ticker

Tags: sprite-kit

I am just getting started on SpriteKit and trying to build a very simple number ticker - like a slot machine with images of 0,1,2....9 inside that have to tick over. Its like a scoreboard where the number below pushes the number above when the score needs to change like a scroll wheel (much like the Date Picker on iOS, but just automated)

My first attempt:

I tried creating a SpriteNode. Then I created 2 other sprite nodes and placed the images 0 and 1 in them. I placed the sprite nodes with the numbers inside its parent sprite node.

But what is happening is that the number 1, placed below number 0 is showing through below the parent Sprite node. I don't want number 1 to show at all till I have to push over number 0 and show number 1. The parent sprite node is 100x100 in size and each number image is about 80x80 in size. So when number 0 is sitting inside the 100x100 sprite and I position the number 1 on the y axis at position -100 (relative to the parent sprite), it is leaking and showing through outside of the parent sprite.

How do I prevent this from happening? Am I even doing the right thing or is there an easier way to do this.

Any pointers on how to make this number ticker work with SpriteKit? Thanks very much

Comment: SKCropNode is the solution of ur problem just try it https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKCropNode_Ref/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It would actually be helpful to include code to help with your explanation.

As dragoneye mentioned, you are going to want to use SKCropNode in conjunction with the hidden property.

You can do that with something like this code below. I've hardcoded the 100 for your 100x100 case, but you should make that adjustable, so you have flexibility if you want to change the size of the mask.

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
SKCropNode *cropNode = (SKCropNode *)self.node;

cropNode.maskNode = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size:size];
```

Then you would add your nodes 0 and 1 via:

```
[cropNode addChild:node0];
[cropNode addChild:node1];
```

where in this case, node0 is your 0 node and node1 is your node1 node.

You should also use hidden to turn off the node you don't need (i.e. when it is no longer needed to be seen). To change numbers, I would probably just change the textures on those nodes. This implies you probably want to preload all the textures for the numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. What is the best way to actually create the ticker effect where 0 is pushed up and 1 replaces it from below? Does changing texture work for that?